# Update not occurring during script

Tags: postgresql

I am running a script that
Creates a table
Copies records into the table using the POSTGRESQL Copy Function
Then I create an enhanced version of the table with additional fields
I insert records from the first into the second table using an Insert into with a select
Then I run an Update to add field description based on a mater file
When I review the second table, there are no updates. However if after a few minutes I run the exact same update, all is good.

```
Update elan_staging.rx_claims  
set proprietary_name=public.ndc.proprietary_name,
non_proprietary_name=public.ndc.non_proprietary_name,
package_description=public.ndc.package_description,
labeler_name=public.ndc.labeler_name
from public.ndc
where ndc_number_code=ndc_11;
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you start your second update before the commit takes place? In that case data is not yet visible for the second transaction.

Comment: I added a commit statement and now it is all good. Thx